# Insert http page into https site

Tags: https

I have a virtual shop hosted under HTTPS domain, for example, https://www.myshop.com
I need to insert an external link of another domain name not hosted in my server to my site. This link can be http or https, no matter.
The only way to insert it is through a script like this:

I'm working with Classic ASP and I have a Windows 2008 server.
I redirected external domain to internal one in web.config
externalSite (secure) -> myshop.com/extSite (secure)
So I changed my code to:

Redirection works perfect.

My problem is that I want that warning in IE of "mixed content" desappears. I'm searching in lots of forums but I can't found any answer that works.
Could someone help me to solve this problem? Is ther any way to avoid this annoying warning?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't avoid it. The message is there for a reason. The page they are viewing is not secure, despite the fact that they visited a secure URL.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx for further discussion.

Comment: In my case it is necessary to include a js script in my https page, there isn't another way to do it. How have I to solve this problem? I see in other forums that it is possible to insert a YouTube video without showing warning message. Is it really no possible to do something with my code to solve that annoying message?

Comment: The only way to get rid of the warning message is to host your javascript on an SSL server and reference it using a https:// URL.